# Proof of cotangent rule in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image: Triangle]

I was reading a textbook and found the following identity for the triangle given in the picture: $$(m+n)\cot(θ)= m\cot(a)-n\cot(b)$$
I tried to prove it using sine and cosine on the triangles but didn't get an expression that seemed to simplify. How should one prove this rule?

Comment: $\theta=\pi/2$?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: Try to use areas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove this rule using the sine law, which gives the following:
$$\frac{n}{\sin b} = \frac{q}{\sin (b+\theta)},$$
$$\frac{m}{\sin a} = \frac{q}{\sin (\theta-a)},$$
where $q$ is the line between both triangles.
If you now write both equations in terms of $q$, you get the following:
$$n \frac{\sin (b+\theta)}{\sin b} = m \frac{\sin (\theta-a)}{\sin a}.$$
Now you can use $\sin (\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta$ to get:
$$n \frac{\sin b \cos \theta + \cos b \sin \theta}{\sin b} = m \frac{\sin \theta \cos a - \cos \theta \sin a}{\sin a}.$$
Simplifying the expression, rearranging the terms and dividing by $\sin \theta$ you get the desired result:
$$(m+n) \cot \theta = m \cot a - n \cot b.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another proof (using geometry) of the theorem is this one

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.