# Calculate the ratio based on the lengths of edges of triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

**The problem**

My problem is,

Let $\triangle ABC$ be an acute triangle, circumscribed in $(O)$ and has orthocenter $H$. Let $HO$ intersect $(O)$ at $E$ and $F$, as shown in the image. $AE$ cuts $BC$ at $K$ and $AF$ cuts $BC$ at $L$. $AO$ cuts $BC$ at $T$. Calculate the value of $\frac{TK}{TL}$ according to the side-lengths and angles of $\triangle ABC$
[image: Illustration here]

My approach is that I used the Anti-Steiner point and then use Menelaus Theorem. But that does not actually relates to $a,b,c$ (which are the side lengths of $BC$, $CA$, $AB$, respectively).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: One observation is $OH \parallel BC \Rightarrow TK/TL=1$.

Comment: I agree with you @Flagged. I think what OP wanted to state is that "Let $HO$ intersect arc-$BC$ at $E$ and $F$". Don't you think so?

Comment: @YNK I meant intersect $(O)$ at $E$ and $F$. I was so absent-minded. Sorry both of you!

Comment: how about this: $(EF,O\infty) \wedge_A (KL,TX)$ and work on the position of point $X$: the meeting of $BC$ with the parallel to $EF$ through $A$?

Comment: Or $[E,F;H,O] =[K,L;D,T]$ wrt A, D being foot of perpendicular from A on BC. Remember that EAF and KAL are right triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

triangle ABC with sides a. b, and c.

$\begin{array}{} A=(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2a},\frac{2S}{a}) & B=(a,0) & C=(0,0) & S=Δ(ABC) \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} \text{Euler line (OH)} & l·x+m·y+n=0 & l=\frac{2a^4-(b^2-c^2)^2-a^2(b^2+c^2)}{2a} & m=\frac{2S(c^2-b^2)}{a} \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} \left\{ D,E \right\}=OH∩Circle(O,r=R)  & R=\frac{abc}{4S} & . \\ K=AD∩BC & L=AE∩BC & T=AO∩BC \\ \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} m_{OH}=tan(ε)=\frac{-l}{m} & ε+θ=π & tan(θ)=\frac{l}{m} \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} \text{triangle ODP} & OP=Rcos(θ) & DP=Rsin(θ) \\ x_{D}=x_{O}-Rcos(θ) & y_{D}=y_{O}+Rsin(θ) & ε+θ=π \\ cos(ϕ)=\frac{±1}{\sqrt{1+tan(ϕ)^2}} & cos(θ)=\frac{m}{ρ} & sin(θ)=\frac{l}{ρ} \\ ρ=\sqrt{l^2+m^2} & x_{O}=\frac{a}{2} & y_{O}=\frac{a(-a^2+b^2+c^2)}{8S} \\ x_{D}=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{Rm}{ρ} &y_{D}=Rcos(α)+\frac{Rl}{ρ} & D+E=2O \\ x_{E}=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{Rm}{ρ} & y_{E}=Rcos(α)-\frac{Rl}{ρ} & cos(α)=\frac{-a^2+b^2+c^2}{2bc}\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} \text{points: K,L,T } & \left| \begin{array}{} x_{A} & y_{A} & 1 \\ x_{D} & y_{D} & 1 \\ x_{K} & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right| =0  & \left| \begin{array}{} x_{A} & y_{A} & 1 \\ x_{E} & y_{E} & 1 \\ x_{L} & 0 & 1 \\  \end{array} \right|=0 & \left| \begin{array}{} x_{A} & y_{A} & 1 \\ x_{O} & y_{O} & 1 \\ x_{T} & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right| =0 \end{array}$

replace everything: $x_{A}$,$y_{A}$,...$R$, $l$,$m$ and $S$. Solve $x_{K}$, $x_{L}$ and $x_{T}$. Simplify

$\begin{array}{} S=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} & s=\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}  \end{array}$

$x_{K}=\dfrac{b (a² - b² + c²) ρ - a c [(a² - c²)² + b² (a² + c²) - 2b⁴]}{a b c [(b² - c²)² + a² (b² + c²) - 2a⁴] - [(b² - c²)² - a² (b² + c²)] ρ} a b$

$x_{L}=\dfrac{b (a² - b² + c²) ρ + a c [(a² - c²)² + b² (a² + c²) - 2b⁴]}{a b c [(b² - c²)² + a² (b² + c²) - 2a⁴] + [(b² - c²)² - a² (b² + c²)] ρ} (-a b)$

$x_{T}=\dfrac{a b² (a² - b² + c²)}{a² (b² + c²) - (b² - c²)²}$

$\begin{array}{} r=\dfrac{TK}{TL} & r=\dfrac{x_{T}-x_{K}}{x_{T}-x_{L}} & r=\dfrac{1-p}{1+p} & \text{where:} \end{array}$

$p=\dfrac{[a² (b² + c²) - (b² - c²)²] ρ}{ a b c [(b² - c²)² + a² (b² + c²) - 2a⁴]}$

$ρ=\sqrt{(abc)^2-(-a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2-b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)}$

[image: fig01]

Answer (score 1):

[image: TKTLRatio]

The easiest way to express the ratio $\dfrac{TK}{TL}$ (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$) in terms of the three angles of an arbitrary acute $\triangle ABC$ is to use the m-n theorem (a.k.a cot theorem) shown in the inset. A proof of this theorem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676023/proof-of-cotangent-rule-in-a-triangle/3304500). But, first we need to do some angle chasing to determine some angles needed for the application of the theorem. To facilitate our work, we add the line segment $QC$, where $Q$ is the point of intersection between the extended $AO$ and the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. Furthermore, for brevity, we let $\measuredangle BAK= \phi$.

Since $AQ$ is a diameter of this circle, we have $\measuredangle QCA = 90^0$. As a consequence, we can express $\measuredangle QCB$ as,
$$\measuredangle QCB = 90^0 -\hat{C}. $$

The two angles, namely $\measuredangle QCB$ and $\measuredangle QAB$, are subtended by the same chord $BQ$ of the circumcircle at its circumference. Hence,
$$\measuredangle QAB= \measuredangle QCB = 90^0 - \hat{C} ,$$
from which it follows that
$$\measuredangle TAK= \measuredangle QAB + \measuredangle BAK = 90^0 - \left(\hat{C} -\phi\right). \tag{1}$$

Since $EF$ is a diameter of the circumcircle, we have $\measuredangle FAE = 90^0$. Therefore,
$$\measuredangle LAT= \measuredangle FAE - \measuredangle TAK = \hat{C} -\phi. \tag{2}$$

According to Euclid I.32., the external angle at the vertex $T$ of the $\triangle BTA$ can be determined as,
$$\measuredangle ATC = \measuredangle ABT + \measuredangle TAB = 90^0 + \left(\hat{B}-\hat{C}\right). \tag{3}$$

Since we now have determined the three required angles, we can apply the m-n theorem to $\triangle ABC$, where the line $AT$ passes through the vertex $A$ and meets the side $BC$ at $T$.
$$\left(TK+TL\right)\cot\left\{90^0 + \left(\hat{B}-\hat{C}\right)\right\} =TK\cot\left\{90^0 - \left(\hat{C} -\phi\right)\right\} – TL\cot\left(\hat{C} -\phi \right)$$

This can be rewritten as,
$$-\left(TK+TL\right)\tan\left(\hat{B}-\hat{C}\right) =TK\tan\left(\hat{C} -\phi\right) – TL\cot\left(\hat{C} -\phi \right).$$

We can use this equation to set up an expression for the ratio $\dfrac{TK}{TL}$ as shown below.
$$\frac{TK}{TL}=\frac{\tan\left(\hat{B}-\hat{C}\right)- \cot\left(\hat{C} -\phi \right)}{ -\tan\left(\hat{B}-\hat{C}\right) - \tan\left(\hat{C} -\phi \right)}$$

Upon simplification of the right hand side of this equation, the above identity becomes,
$$\frac{TK}{TL}=\cot\left(\hat{B} -\phi \right) \cot\left(\hat{C} -\phi \right) =\dfrac{2}{1+\dfrac{\cos\left(\hat{A}+2\phi\right)}{\cos\left(\hat{B}-\hat{C}\right)}}-1. \tag{4}$$

[image: FindingPHI]

We are still in arrear of an expression to determine the value of $\phi$ in terms of the angles of the $\triangle ABC$. Pay your attention to $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, where we have added altitudes $AM$ and $CN$ and drawn two radii $OB$ and $OC$. We also dropped perpendicular $OP$ from $O$ to $BC$, which forced $P$ to be the midpoint of $BC$. Dropping another perpendicular $HG$ from $H$ to $OP$ completes the diagram. Our immediate aim is to find a formula for $\angle GOH$ of the right angle triangle $GOH$, which can be expressed as,
$$\measuredangle GOH = \measuredangle POB + \measuredangle BOE =\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{HG}{OG}\right) \tag{5}$$

Arc $BE$ subtends $\angle BAE$ and $\angle BOE$ respectively at the circumference and the center of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. Therefore,
$$\measuredangle BOE = 2\measuredangle BAE = 2\phi. \tag{6}$$

Similarly, arc $CB$ subtends $\angle CAB$ and $\angle COB$ respectively at the circumference and the center of the same circle. Hence,

$$\measuredangle COB = 2\measuredangle CAB = 2\hat{A}. $$

Since $OP$ is the perpendicular dropped from the apex to the base of the isosceles triangle $COB$,
$$\measuredangle POB = \dfrac{\measuredangle COB}{2} = \hat{A}.\tag{7}$$

According to (5), (6) and (7), we have,
$$\measuredangle GOH = 2\phi + \hat{A} =\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{HG}{OG}\right) \tag{8}$$

Let’s find formulae for $HG$ and $OG$.
$$HG = MP =BP – BM = \dfrac{a}{2} – c\cos\left(\hat{B}\right)\tag{9} $$

$$GP = HM = MC\tan\left(90^0 - \hat{B}\right) = b\cos\left(\hat{C}\right)\cot\left(\hat{B}\right)$$

$$OG  = OP – GP = R\cos\left(\hat{A}\right) - b\cos\left(\hat{C}\right)\cot\left(\hat{B}\right), \enspace\small{\text{where $R$ is the circumradius}} \tag{10}$$

Using using the identity $b=2R\sin\left(B\right)$, (8), (9), and (10), we can obtain the following equation.
$$\small{\hat{A}+2\phi =\tan^{-1}\left\{\frac{\dfrac{a}{2} – c\cos\left(\hat{B}\right)}{ R\cos\left(\hat{A}\right) - b\cos\left(\hat{C}\right)\cot\left(\hat{B}\right) }\right\} = \tan^{-1}\left\{\frac{\sin\left(\hat{A}\right)-2\cos\left(\hat{B}\right)\sin\left(\hat{C}\right)}{\cos\left(\hat{A}\right)-2\cos\left(\hat{B}\right)\cos\left(\hat{C}\right)}\right\}}$$

Simplification of this equation leads to,
$$\hat{A}+2\phi =\tan^{-1}\left\{\frac{\tan\left(\hat{B}\right) -\tan\left(\hat{C}\right)}{ \tan\left(\hat{B}\right) \tan\left(\hat{C}\right)-3}\right\} \tag{11}$$

Once we substitute (11) in (4) to replace the term $\hat{A}+2\phi$, we can call it a day.
$$\cfrac{TK}{TL}=\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{\cos\left\{\tan^{-1}\left(\cfrac{\tan\left(\hat{B}\right) -\tan\left(\hat{C}\right)}{ \tan\left(\hat{B}\right) \tan\left(\hat{C}\right)-3}\right)\right\}}{\cos\left(\hat{B}-\hat{C}\right)}}-1$$